# Corner radius on UIVisualEffectView

Tags: swift, xcode6, cornerradius, uivisualeffectview

Hi Im wondering if It's possible to set a corner radius on a UIVisualEffectView?
Here's the code that i've tried:

```
@IBOutlet var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!

var blurLayer : CALayer{
    return blurView.layer
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpLayer()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func setUpLayer(){
    blurLayer.cornerRadius = 50
}
```

and

```
@IBOutlet var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    blurView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Non of them works.

Comment: Did you try 'blurView.clipsToBounds = true' ?

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm!

Comment: @MikeM Perhaps you should put that into an answer?

Answer (score 67):

After @theMonster suggestion, I am posting what was a comment.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    blurView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    blurView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 9):

in storyboard add two parameter in user-defined runtime attributes `layer.cornerRadius = 8` and `layer.masksToBounds = true`

or in code

```
@IBOutlet var blurView: UIVisualEffectView! {
    didSet {
        blurView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        blurView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] this answer and fixup the formatting. It's hard to know what is explanation and what is code.

Answer (score 6):

Subclass UIVisualEffectView

```
class PSORoundedVisualEffectView : UIVisualEffectView{

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateMaskLayer()
    }

    func updateMaskLayer(){
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 10).CGPath
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

Replace the UIBezierPath with whatever shape you want.

Comment: Thanks! This works really well. But it'd be easier to just make an extension.

Comment: Not really, it's easier like this

Answer (score 5):

All existed solutions are not perfect.

Since `UIVisualEffectView` implements its visual effects by compositing two subviews contents - one is a backdrop view and the other one is a filter view, when you implementing your corner radius by masking the whole `UIVisualEffectView`, there would be some dirty colors around corners.

[image: Dirty Colors Around Corners]

To get rid of these dirty colors, you just need to mask UIVisualEffects's filter view.

```
private typealias ObjcRawUIVisualEffectViewSelCGRect =
    @convention(c) (UIVisualEffectView, Selector, CGRect) -> Void

private var cornerRadiusKey =
"com.WeZZard.Waxing.UIVisualEffectView-CornerRadius.cornerRadius"

private var needsUpdateMaskLayerKey =
"com.WeZZard.Waxing.UIVisualEffectView-CornerRadius.needsUpdateMaskLayer"

extension UIVisualEffectView {
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            if let storedValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(self,
                &cornerRadiusKey)
                as? CGFloat
            {
                return storedValue
            }
            return 0
        }
        set {
            if cornerRadius != newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                    &cornerRadiusKey,
                    newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
                setNeedsUpdateMaskLayer()
            }
        }
    }

    private var needsUpdateMaskLayer: Bool {
        get {
            if let storedValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(self,
                &needsUpdateMaskLayerKey)
                as? Bool
            {
                return storedValue
            }
            return false
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                &needsUpdateMaskLayerKey,
                newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }


    public override class func initialize() {
        swizzle_setBounds()
    }

    private class func swizzle_setBounds() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let selector: Selector = "setBounds:"

            let method = class_getInstanceMethod(self, selector)

            let imp_original = method_getImplementation(method)

            before_setBounds = unsafeBitCast(imp_original,
                ObjcRawUIVisualEffectViewSelCGRect.self)

            class_replaceMethod(self,
                selector,
                unsafeBitCast(after_setBounds, IMP.self),
                "@:{_struct=CGRect}")
        }
    }

    private func setNeedsUpdateMaskLayer() {
        needsUpdateMaskLayer = true
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { [weak self] _ in
            self?.updateMaskLayerIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    private func updateMaskLayerIfNeeded() {
        if needsUpdateMaskLayer {
            updateMaskLayer()
            needsUpdateMaskLayer = false
        }
    }

    private func updateMaskLayer(){
        var filterViewFound = false
        for each in subviews {
            if each.dynamicType.description()
                .containsString("Filter")
            {
                filterViewFound = true
                let newPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: each.bounds,
                    cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius)
                    .CGPath
                if let existedMask = each.layer.mask
                    as? CAShapeLayer
                {
                    existedMask.path = newPath
                } else {
                    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                    shapeLayer.path = newPath
                    each.layer.mask = shapeLayer
                }
            } else {
                setNeedsUpdateMaskLayer()
            }
        }
        assert(filterViewFound == true, "Filter view was not found! Check your hacking!")
    }
}

private var before_setBounds: ObjcRawUIVisualEffectViewSelCGRect = { _ in
    fatalError("No implementation found")
}

private let after_setBounds: ObjcRawUIVisualEffectViewSelCGRect = {
    (aSelf, selector, bounds) -> Void in

    let oldBounds = aSelf.bounds

    before_setBounds(aSelf, selector, bounds)

    if oldBounds.size != bounds.size {
        aSelf.setNeedsUpdateMaskLayer()
    }
}
```

And all things done!

[image: Without Dirty Colors]